# Reading child process' output as soon as some is available?

Tags: c, linux, process, pipe, redirect

I've been trying various methods (popen, pipes + fork/exec, ...) to read a child process' output, all of which are working, but exhibit the same behavior: whenever I try to read the output using `read`/`fread`, it only returns when the buffer is completely full, or when the child exits. I'm looking for a behavior that's more like that of sockets: reading any amount of data as soon as some is available.

How do I do that?

Comment: As others have said, you would have to change the child process to flush the child process buffers to to this. Is the child process a standard Unix utility or something you have access to the source for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally you don't. In particular, the child process will buffer the stream because it won't see a stream connected to a pipe as being "interactive." Since the buffering is happening inside the child process, about the only way to prevent it is to rewrite the code in the child to prevent it from buffering its standard output (either ever, or when passed a particular switch, or perhaps you can add code to detect when it's connected to a pipe and turn off buffering only in that specific case). That, however, can affect the child's performance if it writes much to standard output (especially if you aren't selective about when you disable buffering).

Comment: And if you can't modify the child program, you can make it do line buffering by connecting it to a pseudo-terminal created by a tool such as `script`, `expect`, emacs, etc.

Comment: Gilles has the right idea here. You just need to setup a pty in place of a pipe, and the called program's `stdout` will then default to line-buffered mode.

Comment: @Gilles: ..or you can create a pseudo-terminal pair yourself and connect the child to it (using `posix_openpt()` and related functions).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's possible. The buffering is handled on the child's side, and if it doesn't flush its buffers, there is nothing for you to read. However, a few tools have command line options to control the buffering, e.g. `grep --line-buffered`.